# Can TYPO3 run without local file storage for the typo3temp directory?

Tags: docker, containers, typo3, divio

How should TYPO3 run on a Docker-based architecture such as [Divio](https://www.divio.com) in which:

- multiple containers run in parallel
- are recycled without warning
- have no shared local file storage

It seems that the requirement to write to `typo3temp` (and to some other file locations) is hard-coded in TYPO3.

(By forcing the site to run in just one container instead of multiple containers, it has been possible to create a new admin user and and use the `/typo3` backend. However, there could be other problems arising further down the road.

The application has AWS S3 file storage, and a MySQL database.)

Is there some way around this? How do TYPO3 installations in similar containerised  environments solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

TYPO3 instances need some work on your side for being scaled horizontally.

I am assuming TYPO3 v9+ and a default composer based installation.

You need to share at least `public/typo3temp`, `public/fileadmin` and `./var` between instances. That is because their state is very much tied to the database state. See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/DirectoryStructure/Index.html.

The rest is part of your TYPO3 deployment and could be baked into container images. I am pretty sure for live deployment none of these need to be writable. You might lose some admin backend functionality like through-the-backend configuration changes but that should be obvious.

#### Raising site performance

That said, getting more performance out of TYPO3 is a lot easier with a reverse caching proxy in front of it than by multiplying PHP instances. There is also https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/staticfilecache/ which generates static HTML for cachable content and has a good reputation, too.