# TYPO3 caching issue in clustered deployment

Tags: caching, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have an issue with typo3 and caching.
We have done the following setup:

1 Nginx load balancer (ip_hash i.e sticky sessions)

2 TYPO3 web instances

1 redis cache shared by both typo3 instances

The issue is that when the first web servers serves a given page, it gets cached. As long as the same web server is serving that page, the cached version gets returned.
As soon as the page request is served by the other web served, the full cache get reloaded.
I noticed that additional items are added to the cache although the page content has not changed.

Is there anything I could check to avoid these unnecessary cache reloads?

Answer (score 0):

There are some considerations before scaling TYPO3 horizontally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63594837/2819581

Basically, database/caches and some directories all carry state which is not independent of each other.